# I can't use all my RAM when it's set to the proper frequency

Tags: memory

I have 16 gigs ddr3 evga 1866 sc. When I set it to 1866 via bios, windows 7 say I only have 7.92 usable.

In msinfo32 it shows Virtual RAM as the culprit, however, I have set no paging file on and it is displayed properly in that window. I also checked, unchecked max memory many times in advanced boot options in msconfig . It keeps defaulting to zero. Not saving my setting even when I check the "make these settings permanent"tab.

I've tried multiple bios settings, remapping RAM, idk name it, I've probably tried it. Tried regedit, tried cmd prompt  bcd /set {default} trucantememory blah blah blah ect. Only thing that works is if I set my RAM to 1333.. Then it shows all 16 gigs. But obviously I'd like the faster speed.

Might be this mobo..messed up bios..idk. normally i can't stand it when people say '"I'm not sure but" in this case I'll take any ideas whatsoever.

- AMD 8320 4.8 Ghz
- 16 gigs 1866 ddr3 evga sc currently 1333 Mhz
- Nvidia 1080
- Asus sabertooth 990 fx 2.0
- Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

solved: took out ram and reinstalled it and added a new stick. Somehow, magic insued and it's working normal again.

Answer (score 0):

Release your RAM from the slot and clean it and then reinstall the RAM and then try doing the same. This will definitely work otherwise don't increase the frequency and use it normally.